# RecycleList элементы задать массивом

Tags: android, массивы, recyclerview, arraylist, recyclerview.adapter

Я хочу сделать справочник мед. препаратов для студентов медиков в нем будут такие категории:

> 1. Название препарата
> 2. Доза
> 3. Группа препаратов
> 4. Рецепт на латыни
> 5. Общая информация

Писать под более 600 препаратов их дозу, рецепт, группу препаратов и т.д. - получится очень громадный код и скорее всего будет очень долго обрабатываться. 
Как задать что бы каждый элемент название группа и т.д. задавались массивом.

Вот мой код адаптера

```
public class RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "RecycleViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDoza = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mInform = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia (Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mNames, ArrayList<String> mDoza, ArrayList<String> mGroup, ArrayList<String> mRecipe, ArrayList<String> mInform) {
        this.mNames = mNames;
        this.mDoza = mDoza;
        this.mGroup = mGroup;
        this.mRecipe = mRecipe;
        this.mInform = mInform;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_for_recyclelist, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));
        holder.doza.setText(mDoza.get(position));
        holder.group.setText(mGroup.get(position));
        holder.recipe.setText(mRecipe.get(position));
        holder.inform.setText(mInform.get(position));

        holder.card_farm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        holder.inform.setText("1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        holder.recipe.setText("0");
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 5:

                        break;
                    case 6:

                        break;
                    case 7:

                        break;
                    case 8:

                        break;
                    case 9:

                        break;
                    case 10:

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mNames.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        TextView name, doza, group, recipe, inform;
        CardView card_farm;
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            doza = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doza);
            group = itemView.findViewById(R.id.group);
            recipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe);
            inform = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inform);
            card_farm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_farm);
        }
    }
}
```

**и код активити в котором оно будет отображатся**

```
public class Farmacopea extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, DialogUtilities.OnCompleteListener, BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{


    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDoza = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mRecipe = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mInform = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);
        initNames();
 }
    private void initNames(){

        //0
        mNames.add("1");
        mDoza.add("9");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
        //1
        mNames.add("9");
        mDoza.add("9");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
        //2
        mNames.add("9");
        mDoza.add("");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
        //3
        mNames.add("9");
        mDoza.add("");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
        //4
        mNames.add("");
        mDoza.add("");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
        //5
        mNames.add("");
        mDoza.add("");
        mGroup.add("");
        mRecipe.add("");
        mInform.add("");
 initRecyclerView();
    }
    private void initRecyclerView(){

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.farmlist);
        RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia adapter = new RecycleViewAdapterFarmacopedia(this, mNames, mDoza, mGroup, mRecipe, mInform);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

Пробовал вводить `mNames.addAll();` но к сожалению не знаю как ввести в него массив.

Comment: такие вещи делаются с базой данных, которую можно заполнить заранее на компьютере, а не динамическими списками. затем весь код сводится к тому, что в БД делаются запросы и на экран выводятся результаты этих запросов. массивы в таких задачах только для особо отбитых мазохистов

Comment: Напишите как это сделать массивом пожалуйсто, я начинающий программист и по другому пока не могу написать. БД для меня это очень сложно я уже стыкался с парсингом json баз данных и уже не хочу к ним возвращаться. Пускай будет длинный код и займет много времени но зато понятный мне.

Comment: @VladBulan, про бд это вы зря. Базы данных созданы для помощи програмистам. Зачем вы создаете сколько листов?вам будет достаточно и одного, напишите POJO. Но в данном случае использование динамических структур как источника данных вообще не оправдано. Ваш выход (как было сказано выше) это использование готовой бд в assets. (Примеров очень много https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413959/android-sqlite-connect-to-a-database-in-assets)

Comment: Вы бесконечно правы. Но как я писал выше, базы данных вовсе не мое много раз пробовал SqLite заполнять и все сводилось к тому, что я писал в ручную все строки. По одной простой причине я не могу найти толковый материал по использовании баз данных.

Comment: с моей точки зрения, если что то не понятно/не получается - нужно разбираться и повышать умения, а не собирать что то "из какашек и палок" вопреки всему, потому что делать правильно "не могу". Но если это не ваш путь, то видимо вам нужно [разобраться хотя бы с шаблоном "Master detail flow"](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-masterdetail-flow-tutorial-in-android-studio/), который реализует список каких то пунктов и открытие подробной информации по нажатии на пункт, если вам непременно нужно с массивами, то хотя бы это сделайте, как нормальные люди делают, а не как у вас ужас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите делать без БД (что может быть оправдано только с конечным, непополняемым и "зашитым" на этапе компиляции списком), можете удобно сделать его через создание собственного класса:

```
public class Medicine {
    private String name, doza, group,recipe,inform;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDoza() {
        return doza;
    }

    public void setDoza(String doza) {
        this.doza = doza;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getRecipe() {
        return recipe;
    }

    public void setRecipe(String recipe) {
        this.recipe = recipe;
    }

    public String getInform() {
        return inform;
    }

    public void setInform(String inform) {
        this.inform = inform;
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы удобно было с ним работать из любой точки приложения, создайте такой класс:

```
public class MedLab {
    private static MedLab medLab;
    private ArrayList<Medicine> medicines;

    public MedLab get(Context ctx) {
        if (medLab == null) medLab = new MedLab(ctx);
        return medLab;
    }

    private MedLab(Context ctx) {
        medicines = new ArrayList<>();
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();

        String[] medParams = res.getStringArray(R.array.medParams);

        String[] currentParams;
        for (String medParam : medParams) {
            currentParams = medParam.split("#");
            Medicine medicine = new Medicine();
            medicine.setName(currentParams[0]);
            medicine.setDoza(currentParams[1]);
            ...
            medicines.add(medicine);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Medicine> getMedicines() {
        return medicines;
    }
}
```

Список ваш положите в ресурсы в формате:

```
<string-array name="medParams>
     <item>Имя#Доза#Группа#Рецепт#Информация</item>
     ...
 </string-array>
```

Для получения всего списка в нужном месте напишите `medicines = MedLab.get(текущий контекст).getMedicines();`

В адаптере обращайтесь к текущему элементу (i) и доставайте информацию из него:

```
medicines.get(i).getName();
medicines.get(i).getDoze();
и т.д.
```

[Вот учебник](https://vk.com/doc10903696_267397582?hash=76e02e614aa86e3bcd&dl=9ced34863002d9ec9d), где про это рассказано.