# Насколько плохой этот подход в android-разработке?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Имеется заготовка с информацией, вот 4-хзначный код и описание. Как я это организовал: я во фрагменте вывожу карточки с этими данными. Если взять какой нибудь аналог-предположим, что это глоссарий: имеется ключевое слово и описание.
Имеется идея о таком приложении, но данные уже имеются, которые нужно отображать в CardView. Скажу сразу: были предложения использовать готовую БД, но этот вариант долго не мог реализовать, скорей всего из-за неопытности. Приходилось побайтно переносить все символы в локальную БД, а там и пользоваться...но это было чреватом множества ошибок. Посоветуйте что нибудь, может кто нибудь сталкивался с подобными проблемами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но организовал его я так. Как мне кажется, не должно быть столько однообразных вызовов. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но посмотрев на объём потребляемой памяти-оно не увеличивается в больших количествах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: непонятно, что вы хотите сделать, но плохой) как минимум посмотрите тут (отвечал вчера): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928181/recyclelist-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: jarvis-j, я добавил описание моего приложения(вкратце) в топе вопроса

Comment: вопрос то в чем? в чем конкретно проблема?) делайте `RecyclerView`+адаптер+свой класс (как по ссылке выше) или БД

Comment: вопрос в том, на сколько плох мой метод?
и если с готовой БД, то подскажите толковый ресурс с пояснениями

Answer (score 6):

Проблема в этом коде не столько в объеме потребляемой памяти, сколько в поддерживаемости такого кода. Представьте, что завтра вам надо будет добавить в каждую плитку еще один текст и получится что вам надо написать еще кучу кода.

Начните с простого:

- Создайте класс, состоящий из двух полей: `text1`, `text2`.
- Объявите коллекцию экземпляров этого класса.
- Создайте отдельный метод, который заполнит эту коллекцию данными. (*)
- Перепишите ваш код на цикл, по этой коллекции. Чтобы в цикле перебирались элементы этой коллекции и добавлялись на форму.
- Вернитесь к шагу, который я пометил `*`- ой. Перенесите ваши данные в отдельный ресурс - JSON-файл. Перепишите ваш код так, чтобы данные считывались из этого файла.

После этого можно и о БД подумать. После этого можно подумать о том, чтобы не считывать все названия в память, а запрашивать их по мере необходимости.

Сейчас между тем, что есть и тем, что должно быть - слишком большая пропасть и я не уверен, что прыгать через нее - лучшая стратегия. Разбейте задачу на несколько простых шагов и выполните их последовательно.

Comment: Очень информативный ответ.Спасибо. Последний абзац так вообще мотивирует)